# Detecting keydown event with jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

In my project, there is a button search which seems to be the default button to trigger when the ENTER key has been pressed.

How can I detect a keydown event with jQuery for a login button?

It's an ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the "keypress" event handler to an element using jQuery.

See [.keyPress() in the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Example code:

```
$('#login_button_id').keypress(function(event) {
  //prevent submission when enter key pressed
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```